# Is there a difference between using bootstrap react components vs bootstrap class names?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

In the [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/) guides, examples use bootstrap components like so:

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>1 of 1</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

Is there any difference when comparing the above to the following:

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col">1 of 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass props to the react components, if that is allowed. If there are no props, they basically do the same thing. React components are translated to the html tags with classnames at the end

For example, semantic-ui-react has beautiful documentation that you can see what it is translated to. [Have a look](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/#types-animated)

Comment: I would consider editing to illustrate a code example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one is using the `react-bootstrap` components...

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>1 of 1</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

While this is only using Bootstrap CSS classes (assuming `bootstrap.css` has been included in the React app)...

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col">1 of 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Functionally they are the same, and render the same HTML markup in the browser.